# Cannot remove temp directory after VS 2010 installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory, installation

I cannot remove an installation temp directory "19a5e95b7185dd381eea" and all its sub directories after a successful VS 2010 installation. The OS is Win 7 Sp1. I have Admin privileges. I tried to remove it in Safe Mode with no avail. I cannot change privileges for these directories to delete them. It's read only directory. It's large enough to ignore. How can I delete it?

Solution:

Based on Derek's suggestion, I had to add myself as owner to all sub directories individually. If there is a way to do on the root, if would be easier. After the ownership is given, it was possible to delete all the directories.

Microsoft should create a proper deployment for VS2010 that cleans itself after!

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the ownership of the directory to yourself. It's possible the directory is owned by someone else (like System) and because you don't own it you can't remove it. It's worth a try at least.

Derek

Comment: When I change ownership from SYSTEM to myself then it says I need permission from myself to delete the folder!

Comment: Here's another suggestion. If they are system files then ATTRIB -s would make them non-system and then you might be able to delete them. ATTRIB 19a5e9... would tell you if they have the SYSTEM bit set, ATTRIB -S /S 19a5e9.. Would reset the SYSTEM bit

Comment: Hello Derek, That did not work either. It took a long time to change attributes of all the files in these folders. But at the end I could not delete them still. Then, I went and added myself as owner to all sub folders. Then I was able to delete them all. But I had to do it all the subfolders under 19a5e9... individually! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Learning experience then. Well done finding the problem. Sometimes you look at the muddle the OS leaves you in and you wonder what the developer was thinking ;-)